# Не отрабатывает конструктор

Tags: java, конструктор

Вот мой интерфейс

```
public interface HouseBuilder {

    void addBedroom(int length, int width, Repair repair);

    void addBedroom(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair);

    void addBathroom(int length, int width, Repair repair);

    void addBathroom(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair);

    void addKitchen(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair);

    House buildHouse();

}
```

Это реализация интерфейса

```
public class HBuilder implements HouseBuilder {

    public List<Room> rooms;
    House house;

    @Override
    public void addBedroom(int length, int width, Repair repair) {
        Bedroom bedroom = new Bedroom(length, width, repair);
        rooms.add(bedroom);
    }

    @Override
    public void addBedroom(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair) {
        Bedroom bedroom = new Bedroom(length, width, floorCeramicType, repair);
        rooms.add(bedroom);
    }

    @Override
    public void addBathroom(int length, int width, Repair repair) {
        Bathroom bathroom = new Bathroom(length, width, repair);
        rooms.add(bathroom);
    }

    @Override
    public void addBathroom(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair) {
        Bathroom bathroom = new Bathroom(length, width, floorCeramicType, repair);
        rooms.add(bathroom);
    }

    @Override
    public void addKitchen(int length, int width, FloorCeramicType floorCeramicType, Repair repair) {
        Kitchen kitchen = new Kitchen(length, width, floorCeramicType, repair);
        rooms.add(kitchen);
    }

    @Override
    public House buildHouse() {
        return house;
    }
}
```

Это мой главный класс

```
public class TwoBedroomHouse implements HouseFacilities {

    private HBuilder houseBuilder;

    public TwoBedroomHouse(HBuilder houseBuilder) {
        this.houseBuilder = houseBuilder;
    }

    public void constructHouse() { // метод строит дом
        houseBuilder.addBedroom(100, 100, COSMETIC);
        houseBuilder.addBedroom(120, 120, GRANITE, RENOVATION);
        houseBuilder.addBathroom(40, 50, COSMETIC);
        houseBuilder.addBathroom(40, 40, MOSAIC, DESIGNER);
        houseBuilder.addKitchen(120, 80, MARBLE, DESIGNER);
    }

    List<Room> rooms = houseBuilder.rooms;

    public double getAllHouseArea() {
        double roomArea = 0;
        for (Room room : rooms) {
            roomArea = room.getLength() * room.getWidth();
        }
        return roomArea;
    }
........
}
```

Класс Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HBuilder builder = new HBuilder();
        TwoBedroomHouse twoBedroomHouse = new TwoBedroomHouse();

        System.out.println(twoBedroomHouse.getAllHouseArea());
  }
}
```

Не отрабатывает конструктор, выскакивает исключение "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "rooms" because "this.houseBuilder" is null".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем причина? Что не так?

Comment: В данном коде конструктор `TwoBedroomHouse` с аргументом НЕ вызывается.  Представленный код НЕ компилируется, так как в нем отсутствует дефолтный конструктор.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это случилось потому что вы не передали объект типа `HBuilder` в конструктор класса `TwoBedroomHouse`.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HBuilder builder = new HBuilder();
    TwoBedroomHouse twoBedroomHouse = new TwoBedroomHouse(builder);

    System.out.println(twoBedroomHouse.getAllHouseArea());
}
```

Comment: Хм.. С каких пор код с непереданным аргументом компилируется?

Comment: передала HBuilder в конструктор класса TwoBedroomHouse, но все равно такая же ошибка(

Comment: Кстати, да. Мне так кажется, что Вы компилируете не тот проект, который Вам нужен